# Creating points subsets in django-models

Tags: python, django, django-models, architecture, scalability

I am looking for a scalable way to create new user points subsets without migrating each time a new subset is created.

For example, say I have a `users` app with a model where `total_points` is the sum of `pts_1`, `pts_2`, and `pts_3` for each user.

I have also created a `campaigns` app that enables users to earn points by performing an action (say, clicking a button for simplicity). I can add new campaigns to the platform through the Django admin and set it up so that when users complete the campaigns, they are credited with points such that `(campaign, pk=n)` credits that user's `pts_n`.

However, in order to do this, I need to manually add `pts_n` to `models.py` and migrate to the database. Is there a better solution? The only thing that I can think of is pre-populating `pts_n` in batches to avoid migrating every time I add a new campaign.

Am I thinking about this the wrong way? I am pretty new to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to create a UserPoints model where you record the awarding of points.

```
class UserPoints(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    points_amount = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    points_category = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
```

This model assumes that the category is optional.

Now you can dynamically calculate a user's points:

```
user = request.user
UserPoints.objects.filter(user=user).aggregate(Sum('points_amount'))
```

If you want just the amount of points from a certain category:

```
category = 'my_category'    
UserPoints.objects.filter(user=user, category=category).aggregate(Sum('points_amount'))
```

Your solution where you would constantly be adding `pts_n` columns to the database is clearly not preferable here, since that would be a lot of work and you would be using the `total_points` column as an aggregate of other columns which is not a recommended practice.